# How to search in Mongoose populate array [array containing ref]

Tags: arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm new in MEAN stack development. Please anyone tell how to search in Mongoose populate array. that array containing ref.

**Discussion Schema:**

```
const discussionSchema = new Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  subject_title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
keywords: [
    {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Keyword',
      default: null
    }
}, 
{
  timestamps: true
}
)
```

**Keyword Schema:**

```
const keywordSchema = new Schema({
  keyword:{ 
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true, 
  }
  
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

**How To Search Keyword String In keyword array containing ref ID of Keyword Model.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongoose aggregation and `$lookup` operator to achieve this. `$lookup` is used to join to collections like `populate`.

You have to first join discussion and keywords then search the keyword using `$match` operator.

Suppose that the `matchingKeyword` variable is your query.

```js
let result = await DiscussionModel.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'keywords',
    localField: 'keywords',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'keywords'
  }
}, {
  $match: {
    'keywords.keyword': matchingKeyword
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative ways to use mongoose population

```
await DiscussionModel.find('...')
        .populate({ path: 'user_id', select: '...' })
        .populate({ 
           path: 'keywords', 
           match: { 'keyword': /regExp/ or 'exact match'} 
        }).lean().exec();
```